# Present UINavigationController from UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

CurrentViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "nextNavViewController.h"
@interface CurrentViewController : UIViewController 

{
nextNavViewController *contr;
}
- (IBAction)showNavView:(id)sender;

@end
```

CurrentViewController.m

```
/*..........*/
- (IBAction)showNavView:(id)sender {
    contr = [[nextNavViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"nextNavViewController"bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController: contr animated:YES completion:nil];


}
/* ......... */
```

nextNavViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface nextNavViewController : UINavigationController

@end
```

I have "nextNavViewController.xib" which contains a table , some buttons and customized navigation bar. I want this interface to be loaded but it loads blank navbar with blank screen.

Is the thing i am doing possible? What i have to do to load the customized interface??

Comment: Does this navigation controller have a root view controller?

Comment: It's quite a rarity to see somebody subclass UINavigationController.  You should remove the one in your XIB, and initialize one in code for the push.

Comment: @rdelmar where and what do i have to code to add a root view Controller to NextNavViewController.

Comment: @CodaFi i don't get what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 5):

A couple of things:

1) Careful with the name of your classes. Make sure they follow the [objective-c standards](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH)

2) You don't need to sub-class a `UINavigationController`. If you want to receive some of the capabilities of a `UINavigationController`, just:

```
contr = [[nextNavViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"nextNavViewController"bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *myNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:contr];

[self presentViewController:myNavigation animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Jack, my boy, brilliant as always.  +1 for explaining what I couldn't in the comments.